# Can I create a foreign key and primary key of the same column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to create a composite primary key for the Enrolment table from the (STDNO & CORSNO) columns which they are also a foreign key from Student and Course tables but it keeps giving me errors. also, the same thing happened in student table I need to let each student belong to a department.

Here's what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    STDNO number(8),
    SNAME varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    DEPTNO varchar(2),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Studnet PRIMARY KEY(STDNO,DEPTNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(DEPTNO) REFERENCES Department(DEPTNO)
);

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    DEPTNO varchar2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME varchar2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    CORSNO number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    CNAME varchar2(30),
    DETNO varchar2(30),
    CMAX number(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolment
(
    STDNO number(8),
    CORSNO number(3),
    GRADE number(2),
    EDATE date date default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Enrolment PRIMARY KEY (STDNO, CORSNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(STDNO) REFERENCES Student(STDNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(CORSNO) REFERENCES Course(CORSNO)
);
```

Comment: A FK must reference a complete key.

Comment: You don't show the error messages, are you expecting us to guess?  My guess is that you either should ***not*** have included `DEPTNO` in the `Student` primary key, or that your ***forgot*** to include `DEPTNO` in the foreign key from `Entrolment`.  *(Also, perhaps you're creating the `Student` table before you create the `Department` table?  But, without the actual error messages, knowing **what** to solve for you is like throwing darts at an invisible dartboard.)*

Comment: In current model you cannot identify a student by `stdno`, but a department and student number. That's why foreign key cannot reference by `stdno` and (if it can) current model will not allow you to assign a course to a single student, but to all the students with the same number in different departments. Use a unique `stdno` across all the departments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PRIMARY KEY` should uniquely identify a thing it represents; in the case of a Student, we can assume that the student number should be unique to that student and should be the primary key by itself (as, it is assumed that, you are not going to issue the same student number to two students in different departments).

If you change your code so that `STUDNO` alone is the `PRIMARY KEY` and rearrange the orders of the tables so that the referenced tables are created before the tables that references them then you get:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Department
(
    DEPTNO varchar2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME varchar2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    CORSNO number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    CNAME varchar2(30),
    DETNO varchar2(30),
    CMAX number(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
    STDNO number(8),
    SNAME varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    DEPTNO varchar(2),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Studnet PRIMARY KEY(STDNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(DEPTNO) REFERENCES Department(DEPTNO)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolment
(
    STDNO number(8),
    CORSNO number(3),
    GRADE number(2),
    EDATE date default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Enrolment PRIMARY KEY (STDNO, CORSNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(STDNO) REFERENCES Student(STDNO),
    FOREIGN KEY(CORSNO) REFERENCES Course(CORSNO)
);
```

*(And also fix the typo where you have `date date` in the `Enrolment` table.)*

Then the constraints in the `Enrolment` table work because each of the referential constraints references something unique. Before, you had said that the combination of both student number and department together was unique but were trying to reference just the student number which, by itself, was not unique.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e07529d3826b0c29c0fe1c6d6d20d383)*